# Have the Pyramid Texts been translated into German?

Tags: religion, language, ancient-egypt

I would like to know if the Pyramid Texts have been "officially" translated into German and, if so, where I can find them. I am interested in the texts of Pepi I.

There are some Incantations of Pepi I. listed in a thesis I am working on, which the author took from "The Ancient Egyptian Pyramid Texts" James and Peter, 2005. I found them in English and French, but am desperate searching for the German one, as the Pyramid Texts are very complex, and each detail can ruin a translation.

I checked (the following resources do not have what I'm looking for):

- Hartwig Altenmüllers,
- Louise Gestermann
- the European Library and didn't find anything.

Comment: What is an "official" translation?  What research have you done?

Comment: VtC as trivial; the question is answered in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_Texts), "The texts were first discovered in 1881 by Gaston Maspero, and translations were made by Kurt Heinrich Sethe (in German), Louis Speleers (in French), Raymond O. Faulkner, Samuel A. B. Mercer and James P. Allen (the latest translation in English)."

Comment: Sorry Mark C. Wallace, just saw your answer. Thank you for your comment. There are some Incantations of Pepi I. listed in a Thesis I am working on, which the author took from "The Ancient Egyptian Pyramid Texts" James and Peter, 2005. I found them in English and French, but am desperate searching for the German one, as the Pyramid Texts are very complex, and each detail can ruin a translation. I checked Hartwig Altenmüllers, Louise Gestermann and others, but they don't have what I am looking for. I also checkt The European Library and didn't find anything.

Comment: @Marie-Claire I think it is better to include your comment in the question which shows your research efforts. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. Where is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't read more than a few words in German, so I'll apologise in advance if this is wrong but this appears to be the text of Kurt Sethe's work about the Pyramid Texts (edition published in 1922):

[Die altaegyptischen Pyramidentexte nach den Papierabdrucken und Photographien des Berliner Museums](https://www.archive.org/stream/diealtaegyptisch03sethuoft#page/n5/mode/2up)

Comment: That is correct: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_Texts

Comment: Thank you so much, Steve Bird! It seems to be what I am looking for. Will have a look.

Comment: Gotta love the digital age. Imagine trying to find that back when the internet didn't exist :)

Comment: Exactly AleksandrH! Thanks so much to all!